# Countifs function throws object-definde error

Tags: vba, excel

There are two worksheets that I'm using and when I run the codes it shows me 
run time error

> '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Cells(B, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countifs( _
    Worksheets("L&S - Swing to COB").Range("R2;R805"), _
    Sheet3("Sheet2").Range(H3), _
    Worksheets("L&S - Swing to COB").Range("AZ2:AZ805"), _
    Sheet3("Sheet2").Range("B2"))
```

Can anyone helps me on this ?

Comment: Show the code properly, including declarations etc.

Comment: `R2;R805` that semicolon should be a colon

Comment: What is B? Do you mean Cells(2,2) ? And range H3 should be Range("H3")

Comment: `.Range(H3)` should probably be `.Range("H3")` otherwise `H3` is considered to be a variable. I recommend to use `Option Explicit`. Also `Sheet3("Sheet2")` doesn't make sense use `Worksheets("Sheet2")`

Comment: You could also stick to the worksheets collection.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of syntax errors in that code snippet. Try:

```
Cells(2, "B").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
    Worksheets("L&S - Swing to COB").Range("R2:R805"), _
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H3"), _
    Worksheets("L&S - Swing to COB").Range("AZ2:AZ805"), _
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2"))
```

Changes made:

- `Cells(B, 2)` to `Cells(2, "B")`
- `Range("R2;R805")` to `Range("R2:R805")`
- `Sheet3("Sheet2").Range(H3)` to `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H3")`
- `Sheet3("Sheet2").Range("B2")` to `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")`

Comment: It is `Cells(row, column)` therefore `Cells("B", 2)` won't work but `Cells(2, "B")`